# Trying to Use Google Maps API to See Directions Between 2 Locations but the Map is Spazming. How Do I Fix This?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to use google maps to show the directions between 2 coordinates and it is working but the map is spazming. It keeps resetting to the initial location upon initially zooming out and going between the 2 positions.

```
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, DirectionsService, DirectionsRenderer } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const libraries = ['places'];

export default function Details() {
  const positionA = { lat: 41.8781, lng: -87.6298 };
  const positionB = { lat: 42.8781, lng: -88.6298 }; 

  const containerStyle = { width: '100%', height: '100%' };

  const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null);

  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GMAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries,
  });

  const directionsCallback = (response) => {
    if (response.status === 'OK') {
      setDirections(response);
    } else {
      console.log('Directions request failed due to: ' + response.status);
    }
  };

  if (loadError) return "Error loading maps";

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <section className="contact-container">
        <div className="detail-slot">
          <div style={{ height: "calc(100% - 16rem)" }}>
            {isLoaded && (
              <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                center={positionA}
                zoom={10}
                onLoad={(map) => {
                  const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                  bounds.extend(positionA);
                  bounds.extend(positionB);
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }}
              >
                {positionA && (
                  <Marker position={positionA} />
                )}
                {positionB && (
                  <Marker position={positionB} />
                )}
                {positionA && positionB && (
                  <DirectionsService
                    options={{
                      destination: positionB,
                      origin: positionA,
                      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                    }}
                    callback={directionsCallback}
                  />
                )}
                {directions && (
                  <DirectionsRenderer
                    directions={directions}
                    options={{
                      polylineOptions: {
                        strokeColor: 'red', 
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </GoogleMap>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! : )

It says that the question is mostly code so Im just going to add more words. The code does work and is working well at the start but upon zooming out from the initial location it works properly. But then it then the map keeps resetting back to the initial spot then tries to go back to in between. How do I fix this?

Comment: After some checking it seems that the entire page keeps rerendering and I have no idea why. I put a console.log at the top and now it keeps triggering.

Answer (score 0):

### This an issue within the `react-google-maps/api` library when it comes to rendering the `<DirectionsRenderer />` component

There has been an issue within the library since 2020 and you can find it here: https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/447

As per the author of the library:

> please isolate each component in `React.memo()` and use debounce or
> something, also redux is useful.
>
> eslint with `eslint-plugin-react-perf` - must have to eliminate
> excessive renders

But after reading through the github issue, I found [this comment](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/447#issuecomment-621250443) that helped and modified it a little for this question.

Now to fix the re-renders, you need to use the `useRef` hook as your reference to check if the `DirectionsRenderer` had already rendered or not.

To do this, you have to import the `useRef` hook first.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
```

Then create a `useRef` hook for your renderer and set it to `false` as default like so:

```
const rendererRef = useRef(false)
```

Then inside your `directionsCallback` function, you need to nest another `if` statement to check if the `rendererRef` is `false`, and if it is (which is the default in your first load), it will set the current `rendererRef` into `true` and then proceed with using `setDirections(response)` to render your `<DirectionsRenderer />` component.

```
const directionsCallback = (response) => {
  if (response.status === "OK") {
    if (rendererRef.current === false) {
      // This changes the current `rendererRef`
      // from false to true.
      rendererRef.current = true;
      console.log(rendererRef.current);
      // Proceed to setting the directions state for the
      // DirectionsRenderer to render using the response.
      setDirections(response);
    }
    // This is to monitor if the Directions Service fired.
    console.log("Directions Service Fired.");
  } else {
    console.log("Directions request failed due to: " + response.status);
  }
};
```

What this does is that it will prevent another re-render whenever the `rendererRef` is set to `true`, which solves the re-render issue. You can also utilize this whenever you want this to be a dynamic app wherein you want to change the origin and destination so that you can control when you want to re-render your `<DirectionsRenderer />` component again by setting it between `true` and `false` depending on your use case.

Here's a proof of concept codesandbox for you to check and play around with:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trying-to-use-google-maps-api-to-see-directions-between-2-locations-but-the-map-is-spazming-how-do-i-fix-this-forked-pzm5hr

> **NOTE**: I'd recommend that you don't include your `center` variable
> inside the component because it will cause it to recenter whenever the
> current component rerenders. Also please do use your own `API KEY` on
> the sandbox I provided.

I hope this helps!